# Eloquent relationship between two models that belong to the same model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a **many-to-many** relationship between `Parent` and `Child` but I don't know yet how to express that using **Eloquent relationships**.

[image: Database visualisation]

```php
class Child extends Model
{
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Family::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Parent extends Model
{
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Family::class);
    }
}
```

*(I know I can't name a class **Parent** in PHP, I just dont wanna reveal all my database)*

```php
class Family extends Model
{
    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Parent::class);
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }  }
}
```

I need to set relationships between `Child` and `Parent` through `Family`.

Until now I'm doing:

```php
App\Models\Child::find(1)->family->with(['parents'])->get()
```

Comment: So it was just a misconception in my head:
I had the idea that both **parent** and **child** belong to **family**,
So my only option was similar to
```parents(){
return this->hasManyThrought(Parent::class, Family::class, 'child_id', 'family_id', 'id', 'id');
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
public function parents()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Parent::class, Family::class, 'id', 'family_id', 'family_id', 'id');
}
```